# For-loop mystery in PHP

Tags: php

Using PHP 5.6, why does this code outputs

```
2
5
8
11
```

instead of

```
3
6
9
```

?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i += 2 . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: You're never clearing your $i so your first pass would ouput 2 then your $i is incremented to 3 by your $i++ then 2 more is added to that so outputs 5 then $++ is 6 then plus 2 = 8 etc etc

Comment: On the first loop through, `i` is equal to 0, then 2 is added to it and the value is echoed. At the end of the loop, it is incremented. On the next pass through, 2 is added to what is now 3, therefore 5 is echoed. The value is incremented, so now it's 6. On the next loop through, 2 is added to i and 8 is echoed. It is then incremented to the value of 9. 9 is less than 10, so it goes through the loop one more time. 2 is added and echoed out as 11. It is incrmented to 12. 12 is not less than 10, so the loop stops.

Comment: maybe use another var than the one that is iterating the for-loop :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because i starts at 0, not 1. Lets see what is happening:

**Loop 1**

```
Initiate i, i = 0;
Check for loop condition ($i < 10). i is 0 so yes, run the loop.
Add 2 to i and echo. 0 + 2 = 2, echo 2.
End of loop, add 1 to i. i is 3.
```

**Loop 2**

```
Check for loop condition ($i < 10). i is 3 so yes, run the loop.
Add 2 to i and echo. 3 + 2 = 5, echo 5.
End of loop, add 1 to i. i is 6.
```

And so on. So you add 2, echo out then add 1.

You may be expecting the `i++` in the for loop to run before the code, but it runs at the *end* of the code. From the [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

> At the end of each iteration, `expr3` is evaluated (executed).

If you want your output to be 3, 6, 9 then you would need to initiate i to 1 at the start of your loop.

```
for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
```

Comment: For it to work well, he could also use `++$1` couldn't he? Or did i mix up something?

Comment: @lino No, he couldn't. No matter what, the `$i++` isn't run until after the loop completes, so `++$i` or `$i++`, it still doesn't add until after the loop runs.

Comment: ok, then I mixed up something and thank you for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 3):

The increment (`i++`) in the loop header happens *after* the loop body is executed. So, `i` is initialized to 0, then you add 2 and print it. Then, the loop header increments it to 3, then you add 2 and print it again...

Answer (score 2):

In the first iteration, you add `0 + 2`, because you declared $i to be `0`, so the output would be 2. then with the `$i++` you do the same as you would write `$i += 1`. So now the value of `$i` is 3.

Then you add again 2 which gives you 5 as an output, then you add another 1. Value of $i = 6, add 2... outputs 8... add 1... add 2... outputs 11...